# How to modify the function of generating random numbers from a pdf to run faster

Tags: r, simulation

Below is the code of generating the random numbers from pdf:

[image]

I modify the code from a function rcmp (package COMPoissonReg).

```
  dcomp <- function(y,mu,v,z=NULL, max=100)
    {
      if (is.null(z)){
      z=sum(sapply(  0:100, function(j) (( ((mu)^j) / (factorial(j)) )^v)  ))
      }
      log.ff <- v*y*log(mu)-v*lgamma(y) - log(z)
      return(exp(log.ff))
    }

    rcomp <- function(n, mu, v, max=100)
    {
      if (length(mu) == 1) {
        mu <- rep(mu, n)
      }
      if (length(v) == 1) {
        v <- rep(v, n)
      }
      u <- runif(n)
      y <- numeric(n)
      z=sum(sapply(  0:100, function(j) (( ((mu)^j) / (factorial(j)) )^v)  ))
      for (i in 1:n) {
        px <- dcomp(y[i], mu[i], v[i],z=z[i], max = max)
        while (px < u[i]) {
          y[i] <- y[i] + 1
          px <- px + dcomp(y[i], mu[i], v[i], z=z[i],max = max)
        }
      }
      return(y)
    }
```

However, the function took a very long time to simulate random variates, is there a way to modify this code to run faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your code which is causing your implementation to take a long time.

The density function `dcomp` should be modified as follows

```
dcomp <- function(y,mu,v,z=NULL, max=100) {
  if (is.null(z)){
    z=sum(sapply(  0:100, function(j) (( ((mu)^j) / (factorial(j)) )^v)  ))
  }
  log.ff <- v*y*log(mu)-v*lgamma(y+1) - log(z)
  return(exp(log.ff))
}
```

Note that you need to add 1 to `lgamma` as gamma(x+1) = factorial(x).

In the function `rcomp` where you generate the random variables you have a problem in

- `sum(sapply(  0:100, function(j) (( ((mu)^j) / (factorial(j)) )^v)  ))`

  The `sum` in this line collapses the vectorization. You need to update it to get a proper vector with individualized values of `z`. I have removed this precalculation in the code below and just do the computation inside `dcomp` but doing the precalculation with certainly save time.

The updated `rcomp` function looks like this

```
rcomp <- function(n, mu, v, max=100)
{
  if (length(mu) == 1) {
        mu <- rep(mu, n)
      }
      if (length(v) == 1) {
        v <- rep(v, n)
      }
      u <- runif(n)
      y <- rep(0, n)  # Have changed this line to force zeros as starting points
      # z=sum(sapply(  0:100, function(j) (( ((mu)^j) / (factorial(j)) )^v)  ))
      for (i in 1:n) {
        px <- dcomp(y[i], mu[i], v[i], max = max) # Not using z
        while (px < u[i]) {
          y[i] <- y[i] + 1
          px <- px + dcomp(y[i], mu[i], v[i],max = max)  # Also not using z
        }
      }
      return(y)
    }
```

Hope this helps!